# COMException when trying to update EDMX from DB after separating POCO classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, edmx

When Test.edmx, Test.context.tt, & Test.tt were all together, I was able to update edmx from db with no issues.

After separating Test.tt class from EDMX & moving it to a new project where all the POCO classes reside, I started seeing the below exception when trying to update edmx.

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is: 'A file or folder with the name 'Test.Context.tt' already exists. Please give a unique name to the item you are adding, or delete the existing item first.'.

**Environment**

Visual Studio 2013 with Update 5

Entity Framework 6.1.3

.NET Framework 4.5.1

Console Application & a Class Library.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I freaked out looking for a solution, but at the end found out that ignoring the exception is of no harm. It's just trying to rewrite the tt file, and it's not a necessarily step in updating your model really.

The edmx gets updated as expected, and you can run the custom tool for your tt files that are scattered everywhere, and they will work nicely.
Just make sure that all the tt files are linked to the edmx file.

const string inputFile = @"..\YourProject\Model.edmx";

Answer (score 0):

When having in the Microsoft Visual Studio message like below

> An exception of type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is: 'A file or folder with the name `Test.Context.tt` already exists. Please give a unique name to the item you are adding, or delete the existing item first.'.

all you need to do is to **remove** the `Test.Context.tt` and `Test.tt` text template files (`.tt`). A new files will be recreated by the Visual Studio automatically.